# Remove pending changes but DON"T 'UNDO' my changes from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

I edit about 50 files in 20 different folders. When I check out for edit, I mistakenly used 'ctrl+a' and selected all folders along with all files in it. That's about 1000 files that I didn't touch at all being included in Pending Changes. How do I remove them from pending changes without "UNDO" my fix for those 50 files?

Answer (score 2):

You could shelve the files you're interested in, undo everything, check out the files you're interested in, unshelve the pending changes, then check in your changes.

Or you could just check everything in and let TFS ignore the unchanged files.

Comment: when you shelf, doesn't it shelf everything in pending change regardless what were actually changed(the 50 files)?

Comment: How do you let TFS ignore unchanged files?

Comment: 1 - you can select the specific files you want to shelve, regardless of what's checked out or has pending changes.
2 - it doesn't actually "ignore" them but if there are no changes to a given file it doesn't check anything in.

Answer (score 1):

[I work with TFS 2010] When doing checkin TFS checks if file was changed. So it is safe to do  checkin all files. Not changed files will not be included in changeset.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the files via FileExplorer, Undo through TFS, and then add the files back where they were.